# Method Arguments and Local Variable are Thread Safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Can anyone confirm below statement?

> Method Arguments and Local Variable declared inside a method is Thread
>   safe; both are exclusive for each invocation of the Thread.
>
> On the other hand Global Variable is shared.

For instance

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{

    int _tmp = 10;      //SHARED BETWEEN t1, t2, t3, and so on

    public void run(){

        testThreadConcurrency(arg); // arg  is EXCLUSIVE FOR ALL invocation of testThreadConcurrency
    }

    public void testThreadConcurrency (int num){

        int tmp = 10;   //EXCLUSIVE FOR ALL invocation of testThreadConcurrency()

    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MyThread _runn = new MyThread();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(_runn,"t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(_runn,"t2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(_runn,"t3");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();             
        t3.start()
}
```

**

> Please check the output of below program which prove that Global
>   variables are SHARED

**

```
public class ThreadDemo {

    static Object _lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MyThread _runn = new MyThread();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(_runn,"t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(_runn,"t2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(_runn,"t3");
        t1.start();
        try {Thread.sleep(300);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        t2.start(); 
        try {Thread.sleep(300);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        t3.start(); 

        try {Thread.sleep(300);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        synchronized(ThreadDemo._lock){ThreadDemo._lock.notify();}

        try {Thread.sleep(300);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        synchronized(ThreadDemo._lock){ThreadDemo._lock.notify();}


        try {Thread.sleep(300);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
        synchronized(ThreadDemo._lock){ThreadDemo._lock.notify();}


    }

}

class MyThread implements Runnable{

    int _tmp = 10;

    public void run(){

        testTestConcurrency();
    }

    public void testTestConcurrency(){

        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t2"))
        {
            _tmp = 20;          
        }

        synchronized(ThreadDemo._lock){try {ThreadDemo._lock.wait();} catch (InterruptedException e) {}}

        System.out.println("_tmp = "+_tmp+"|"+Thread.currentThread().getName());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not exactly**:

T1's `_tmp` is not shared with T2's `_tmp` since they are distinct `MyThread`'s instances (**not class' variables but instance's variables**).

Indeed, you reinstantiate the whole class each time you create a thread:

```
new MyThread
```

It would be different if attributes were actually class variables:

```
static int _tmp = 10;
```

In this case you might need some synchronization mechanism (`synchronized` block, or `volatile` keyword or anything else adapted to the situation)

I would rephrase it to:

> Method Arguments and Local Variable declared inside a method is Thread
>   safe; both are exclusive for each invocation of the Thread.
>
> However, **a same instance** of any class dealing with one or more global variables
>   shares those ones among hitting threads.

It is a best practice to avoid the maximum of shared instances among threads, to avoid the need to synchronize everything (as long as performance/memory isn't too hurt).

Thus your code snippet follows the best practice :)

**-----------COMMENT ABOUT YOUR ADDED CODE SNIPPET--------------**:

```
MyThread _runn = new MyThread();  //you are using the same instance here ! delete this line
```

So, indeed, in this case the attribute would be share if you reuse this instance when declaring each thread:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(_runn,"t1");
Thread t2 = new Thread(_runn,"t2");
Thread t3 = new Thread(_runn,"t3");
```

Replace by just:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread(), "t1"); //a new MyThread instance for each thread !
Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread(), "t2");
Thread t3 = new Thread(new MyThread(), "t3");
```

Will output (as expected :)):

```
_tmp = 10|t3
_tmp = 10|t1
_tmp = 20|t2
```

Comment: Updated with an explanation

Comment: I agree with you, with different Runnable t1, t2 and t3 treat _tmp as a EXLUSIVE resource. If i make it "static" then again its become SHARED among all of them. My question is why "volatile" is not working at that place...to make it SHARED resource like as "static"

Comment: Of course, `static` make it shared. `volatile` has nothing to do with this sample. It just allows memory barrier.  `volatile` has no direct link with `static`. Both are distinct concepts. `volatile` forces the main memory to be updated with the latest value of the concerned field BEFORE another thread reads the field's value. It acts as an "happens-before". `volatile` doesn't SHARE something itself.

Comment: I don't see any point in your qualification. Global variables (i.e. in Java static variables) are shared, period. It has nothing to do with instances. You might want to add *another* paragraph about instance variables, but what you've added about global (static) variables is pointless.

Comment: @EJP Agreed, but in some people mind, global word might be applied to instances variables, i.e persistent inside the object's scope. Why? Because I saw too many people defining an object's field using the term global field for the object. I wanted to be more accurate about its assertion and its used terms. Even the brought "proof" of the poster confirms that people deals with "global" term for field's instance (cf OP post)

Comment: Mik you are right.

    class Test{
     
     int var1; //Global Variable/Instance Variable
     static int var2; //Class Variable

    }

Sorry! All confusion creates since I would like to make a test App to demonstrate the usage of “volatile”.

But, now I come to know that it’s not possible to show it using small program since it’s related with memory visibility.

If I create N-number of thread using same Runnable object then all Thread will be pointing to same Global members. We can say, in that case Global Variables behaves like a Class variable.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful!  Arguments and variables are not objects.  Suppose that several threads each enter a method that manipulates a List:

```
public Foo mumbler(List<Bar> barList) {
    ...
}
```

Each invocation of the method has its own unique barList *variable*.  It can not be accessed by any other thread, but if all of those variables hold references to the same List object, then the threads still can (and probably will) corrupt the List if they don't prevent it by mutual exclusion or by some other means.

Edit:

> I forgot Java pass primitives as a CallByValue but use CallByReference in case of References....

A better way to say that is, Java passes object references *by value*:

In C++ you could write this:  (not that you'd ever *want* to write it :-)

```
pushValueOnStack(my_type_t value, struct node &top) {
    struct node new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->next = top;
    top = new_node;
}
```

If you had a local variable, *myStack*, and you called `pushValueOnStack(someValue, myStack),` it would actually change your local variable to point the stack's new top node.  That's call-by-reference.  That never happens in Java.

Comment: Thanks James! to correct me. I forgot Java pass primitives as a CallByValue but use CallByReference in case of References.So if arguments are of type reference then those are not Thread safe.

Comment: Once again Thanks James! you clear my concept. Yes, Java passes by value only and Reference having just one advantage over Primitives is that we can manipulate it but for swap both having same effect; means we cant make it likewise in C/C++ with the help of CallByReference/CallByAddress

Answer (score 0):

> Method Arguments and Local Variable declared inside a method is Thread safe; both are exclusive for each invocation of the Thread.

Each invocation of the *method.* There is no such thing as 'invocation of the Thread', and if there was, it isn't sufficiently inclusive. 'Invocation of the method' covers the case of recursion as well as the case of multi-threading.

> On the other hand Global Variable is shared.

Yes.